# Get BHID_LinkTargetItem from a .lnk file if IsShortcut was deleted from the registry

Tags: winapi, com

I have a *[IShellItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* object created from a .lnk file, and I want to obtain the file it points to, either as another *IShellItem* or as a PIDL. Because the target may not be an actual file (merely an item in the virtual file system), I would like to refrain from using any paths at all.

The closest method I found is *[IShellItem::BindToHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*, which accepts *BHID_LinkTargetItem* as the argument, and obtains the target as an *IShellItem*. That's perfect, but there is a slight problem - it doesn't work if I delete the `IsShortcut` registry key in HKCL (in `lnkfile` etc.). Calling [*IShellItem::GetAttributes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't return *SFGAO_LINK* in that case, and the method fails.

It's no surprise that system functions stop working when tampering with the registry, but it is a common thing to remove this specific key, to hide the arrows from the shortcut icons. I know there is probably a better way to do it, but I don't want my code to fail if the user has done this.

What I have currently resolved to, is constructing an *[IPersistFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* at the location and casting it to *[IShellLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*. Now I just call *[IShellLink::GetIDList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* and I am happy. If the shell item is not a real file, I try to obtain the link as specified in the second paragraph.

However, the fact that I have to obtain the path to the link file is what worries me a bit. Are there some cases where this could fail for a valid link object? Can it be done without having to work with paths?

Comment: Continuing the path of providing workarounds for user-created mess will only lead to the dark side ;-). Instead you should tell them the proper way of hiding the shortcut arrow which is to [replace it with a transparent icon](http://www.theeldergeek.com/windows_7/shortcut_remove_arrow_overlay.htm). I think this still works for Win 10. There are even free tools that can do that without manually tampering with the registry.

Comment: @zett42 Good point, but I am not looking for a "hack" or workaround, just an alternative solution to the problem. Also being able to obtain an *IShellLink* directly from an *IShellItem* would be useful.

Comment: Fair enough. [Raymond Chen does that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100702-00/?p=13523/) via `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()`, obtaining an `IShellLink` in the result. As you are starting with an `IShellItem`, you could propably call `IShellItem::BindToHandler()` with `BHID_SFUIObject` to obtain the `IShellLink`. I don't know if this depends on the `IsShortcut` registry key too, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks! I tried `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()` before, but I had to construct the folder from the shell item. `BHID_SFUIObject` is way better, and works no matter the registry.

Comment: Removing something from the registry is nuts, the correct way to remove the arrow is to set the overlay icon to a blank icon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain an [`IShellLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx) directly from an [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) by calling [`IShellItem::BindToHandler()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761134(v=vs.85).aspx) and passing `BHID_SFUIObject` for the `rbhid` parameter. Then call `IShellLink::GetIDList()` to obtain the link target as you already do in your current solution.

In my test under Windows 10 it worked independently from the existence of the `IsShortcut` registry entry.

**Example:**

```
#include <ShlObj.h>     // Shell API
#include <atlcomcli.h>  // CComPtr
#include <atlbase.h>    // CComHeapPtr
#include <iostream> 
#include <system_error>

// Throw a std::system_error if the HRESULT indicates failure.
template< typename T >
void ThrowIfFailed( HRESULT hr, T&& msg )
{
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw std::system_error{ hr, std::system_category(), std::forward<T>( msg ) };
}

// RAII wrapper to initialize/uninitialize COM
struct CComInit
{
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize( nullptr );
    CComInit() { ThrowIfFailed( hr, "CoInitialize failed" ); }
    ~CComInit() { ::CoUninitialize(); }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        CComInit init;

        // Create a shell item from a file for testing purposes.
        CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
        ThrowIfFailed(
            SHCreateItemFromParsingName( L"C:\\test.lnk", nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pItem ) ),
            "Could not create shell item from path" );

        // Obtain a link object from the shell item.
        CComPtr<IShellLink> pLink;
        ThrowIfFailed(
            pItem->BindToHandler( nullptr, BHID_SFUIObject, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pLink ) ),
            "Could not obtain IShellLink" );

        // Get the link target as PIDL.
        CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidlTarget;
        ThrowIfFailed(
            pLink->GetIDList( &pidlTarget ),
            "Could not get link target as PIDL" );

        // Create a shell item from the link target PIDL...
        CComPtr<IShellItem> pItemTarget;
        ThrowIfFailed(
            SHCreateShellItem( nullptr, nullptr, pidlTarget, &pItemTarget ),
            "Could not create shell item for link target" );

        //... to obtain the display name (we may use SIGDN_FILESYSPATH to obtain a
        // path only if we know  the target is a filesystem item).
        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> pDisplayName;
        ThrowIfFailed(
            pItemTarget->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEEDITING, &pDisplayName ),
            "Could not get display name of link target" );

        std::wcout << L"Link target (display name): " << pDisplayName.m_pData << '\n';

        return 0;
    }
    catch( std::system_error const& e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << ", error code: " << e.code() << "\n";

        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- The code uses ATL COM smart pointers for exception-safe, clean code. `CComPtr` is used to manage COM objects (its destructor automatically calls the `Release()` method when the object goes out of scope). `CComHeapPtr` is used to manage "raw memory" allocated by the shell (its destructor automatically calls `::CoTaskMemFree()`).

Comment: I think it may not work for custom shell namespace extensions as IShellLink implementaton is not mandatory. In this case, the IShellLink implementation is provided by the shell itself, and I suspect in this case we'd be back to the original question.